# PGSQL - Combining many AND + OR in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table format:

```
| productid | price          |
| ----------| -------------- |
| 1         | 10             |
| 2         | 20             |
| 3         | 30             |
| 4         | 40             |
```

Let's say I want to select all rows where:
(productid is 1 and price is over 50) OR
(productid is 2 and price is over 100) OR
(productid is 3 and price is over 20)

Is there a better generic way to achieve it (something with like arrays with indexes or something) other that do one at a time like:

```
select * from table where (productid = 1 and price > 50) OR
                          (productid = 2 and price > 100) OR
                          (productid = 3 and price > 20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a values clause:

```
select * 
from the_table t
  join ( 
     values (1, 50), 
            (2, 100), 
            (3, 20)
  ) as p(productid, price) 
    on t.productid = p.productid 
   and t.price > p.price;
```

Comment: Just what I needed, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
with conditions as (
select a[1]::int as product_id, a[2]::int as min_price
from (select regexp_split_to_array(unnest(string_to_array('1,50;2,100;3,20', ';')),',')) as dt(a)
)
select t.* from my_table t
  inner join conditions c on t.product = c.product_id
    and t.price >= c.min_price
```

test data:

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create temp table if not exists my_table(product int, price int, note text);
insert into my_table
select 1,10, 'some info 1:10' union all
select 1,20, 'some info 1:20' union all
select 1,50, 'some info 1:50' union all
select 2,20, 'some info 2:10' union all
select 2,100, 'some info 2:100:1' union all
select 2,100, 'some info 2:100:2' union all
select 3,30, 'some info 3:30' union all
select 4,40, 'some info 4:40';
```

result:

```
1   50  "some info 1:50"
2   100 "some info 2:100:1"
2   100 "some info 2:100:2"
3   30  "some info 3:30"


unnest(string_to_array('1,50;2,100;3,20', ';'))-- split CSV to rows
regexp_split_to_array(....,  ',') -- split CSV to columns
```

Comment: Thanks alot, very interesting solution!